# Lambda functions in flux storm configurations

Tags: lambda, apache-storm, flux

I need to pass a lambda function as a parameter to a constructor or method in a flux YAML configuration file (to be used by Apache Storm).

For example, say I want to create an instance of `org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.ByTopicRecordTranslator`. It has a constructor with the following signature:

```
public ByTopicRecordTranslator(Func<ConsumerRecord<K, V>, List<Object>> func, Fields fields)
```

In Java, I would instantiate it like so:

```
ByTopicRecordTranslator<String, String> translator = new ByTopicRecordTranslator<>((K) -> new Values(K.value()), new Fields("oneOrMoreStrings"));
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to do so in the flux YAML configuration file. Here is the code I attempted, that fails:

```
  - id: "field"
    className: "org.apache.storm.tuple.Fields"
    constructorArgs:
      - ["oneOrMoreStrings"]

  - id: "KafkaMessageTranslator"
    className: "org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.ByTopicRecordTranslator"
    constructorArgs:
      - (K) -> new Values(K.value())
      - ref: "field"
```

Here is the error I received:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find a suitable constructor for class 'org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.ByTopicRecordTranslator' with arguments '[(K) -> new Values(K.value()), [oneOrMoreStrings]]'.
    at org.apache.storm.flux.FluxBuilder.buildObject(FluxBuilder.java:358)
    at org.apache.storm.flux.FluxBuilder.buildComponents(FluxBuilder.java:421)
    at org.apache.storm.flux.FluxBuilder.buildTopology(FluxBuilder.java:101)
    at some.package.KafkaConsumerTestTopology.main(KafkaConsumerTestTopology.java:20)
```

I can't find anything about it in the  [flux docs](http://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/flux.html). I'm fairly certain it has to do with how I'm formatting the lambda.

How can I pass a lambda function as a parameter to a constructor or method in a flux YAML configuration file?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I edited your post to make it little more crisp (to many 'seem to's). I removed the YAML tag as it is inappropriate (your problem is not with YAML, just like it is not with ASCII or UTF-8, you are just using that through flux. It is also better to ask questions directly, about programming, instead of your question about peoples capabilities that can only correctly be answered by yes or no. If you don't like the changes, you can roll these back (use the edit link above my name icon). As a YAML-guy I cannot help you further, don't know about flux.

Comment: @Anthon Thank you for the edit, it reads much better now. I appreciate it!